# Autocomplete input value from big static Json file with key value pairs using asp.net core 2.2

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to the ASP.NET enviroment. Currently using ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC and trying to build my first project.
After a lot of research and attempts I didn't succeed to autocomplete the value given on input text box using JQUERY UI Autocomplete.

I have a JSON file stored in some folder inside my project repo (image below).
The Json file contains thousends of key value pairs dicts: `[{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': val2}, {'key1': 'val3', 'key2': 'val4'}]`.

The Json file location location in the image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsEBn.jpg

I have in my _Layout head the Jquery script included.

This is My index.View()

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
@*<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">*@
@section Scripts{
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#searchInput").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "../Data/Places40.json",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { Prefix: request.term ?? ??},
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {'?? ??'};
                            }))

                        }
                    })
                },
                messages: {
                    noResults: "", results: ""
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
}

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class=" row">
        <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
            <h3 class="text-left mb-3">Input:</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="searchInput" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="please type something." />
            </div>
            <div id="match-list">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like it to autocomplete the input given in `#searchInput` textbox.

Comment: Don’t use http post for this.

Comment: As denoted you should not use `Post` but rather `Get` and I believe that auto complete through jQuery only has 250 limit.

Comment: @Vidmantas Blazevicius Thanks, I will change it. what about the 'data' and 'return' section? how can i return for example 2 Values (at the same dictionary) as a result?

Comment: @Greg does it even right to call the json file? or should i use controller and model and pass it to the Jquery function as a list?

Comment: The question would be what are you attempting to do?  A thousand entries in a configuration file do you really want to maintain from a file?  Also you may reach the component limitation, so the concept of batching may be better suited but I am not sure what you're attempting to actually do.

Comment: @Greg I have Json file with lot of data, my goal is it do use this data to autocomplete value given in text box (it should search from different keys and represent a string from different keys too. later, this input will be used to make a search from another json file (there i will need the batching system). Thanks you for you time btw :)

Comment: @greg I think i need first to define a Contreller that return this json file as a string, am i right? or can i use the json file as it is directly?

Comment: That is the part that is odd to me, because you can actually read the JavaScript Object directly into a Plain Old C# Object, which would store the contents into memory.  So your Controller could simply return a key value pair to have Ajax and JQuery to build your dropdown.  Or you could Ajax the Controller and simply take that JSON to be parsed through JavaScript to output to the UI.  The issue you likely have is you have multiple inputs that vary based on bound context selection.

Comment: @greg I used fetch method to save the json data into a javascript variable and then used this variable as a parameter to use the autocomple function of jquery. but as i understood it is a misstake and i need to save the json data on the 'server-side' and work from there. how should i do it?